# React-Native / Navigation : I want to detect wether the user is navigating backward between pushed screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

If I'm moving forward, pushing the same component/screen with different data, I'm able to detect wether the screen is mounting, and then trigger an action within a useEffect.

When it comes to navigating back through the previous screens, seems like I'm not able to detect that the component / screen is changing.

I tried 2 different approaches:

- I was not able to assign any action top the back arrow without overriding the native back arrow with a custom component and then assigning the action to onPress  ( I don't want this solution )
- A better approach was to assign the navigation index as a dependency to a useEffect and then trigger the action when it changes. It works for navigating forward but not backward.

I think this is something very common (e.g navigating between profiles on LinkedIn). Are there other approaches I should try ?

Here's some piece of code :

```
 const navIndex = useRef(0);
 
  useNavigationState((state) => {
    return (navIndex.current = state.index);
  });

 useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Current navigation index : ', navIndex.current);
  }, [navIndex]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the way I used useNavigationState was not ideal.

Instead, this seems to work :

```
  const state = useNavigationState(state => state);

  useEffect(() => {
  
    console.log('Navigation state : ', state);

  }, [state]);
```